# Change R levels without changing factor value

Tags: r, factors, levels

I have a dataframe in R, with 1 factor variable, **Model**. It is representing the smartphone model of my record. Important to note is that this dataframe has *only 1 row*.

The value of the Model column is constructed by converting a character vector (also of length 1) to a factor vector. So initially, the number of levels is 1. I want to change the levels of this variable to the same levels of another factor vector. I do this by

```
levels(resultFrame) <- levels(vectorContainingLevels)
```

However, by doing this, the value of my factor value in Model itself changes to the first level in the vectorContainginLevels vector. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do something like :

```
fact = as.integer(resultFrame) 
levels(resultFrame) <- levels(vectorContainingLevels)
resultFrame = as.factor(fact)
```

I'm not 100% sure but give it a try. (Didn't have enough rep to comment)